# API with a PHP / MVC set up

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, api-design

Hi & thank you for reading me :
I have an MVC webApp with the following set up:

- Root folder with the below .htaccess :

  ```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(.*)\.(png|jpg)$
  RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
  ```

which redirects all to the 'Public' folder containing ,in turn, the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This works absolutely fine to redirect all requests to controllers etc..
I would like to write 2 specific  and  separate rules , (I guess the rule for rewriting would be similar in principal).
I'm not asking for the rule  (even if that would
be great !) but something like :

```
definition/([a-zA-Z\-]+) ?p=word.word_show&action=read_word_data&word=$1
// OR
RewriteRule api/([a-zA-Z\-]+) ?p=api.word.word_show&action=read_word_data&word=$1
```

does not work & I don't understand why ...

There are no folders named 'definition' or 'API' and I don't "intend" to create them...

Many thanks for heading me in the right direction...

Hi again and thanks !
I have gone  online so that you can review, but still not working:
The .htaccess is as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php
    RewriteRule api/([^/]*)$ index.php?p=api.word.word_show&action=read_word_data&word=$1 [L]
```

website url: `www.dictionnaire-commercial.com`

When adding the substitution URL :

`index.php?p=api.word.word_show&action=read_word_data&word=whatever`

The script works...

There is something wrong with the .htaccess script but I can't figure what

Comment: What happens with this code? Do you get an error?

Comment: "does not work & I don't understand why ..." - But you've not stated what it is you are trying to do or what URL you are requesting or where exactly is this rule being used? So, how can we determine whether that rule should work or not? There are some alarm bells... you are rewriting the request to a query string string only - what file are you expecting to handle the request? You've not anchored the regex. You are missing the `L` flag. And if you've placed this rule at the end of the file then that is a problem. (_Aside:_ The first rule in your root `.htaccess` file is entirely superfluous.)

Comment: HI & thanks fo your review...
When I say that it does not work I mean that the redirect leads ...nowhere , I get a blank page, , but the requests themselves ,( eg.  "?p=word.word_show&action=read_word_data&word=$1" or "?p=api.word.word_show&action=read_word_data&word=$1" both work properly  
the file I expect to handle the request is index.php, placed just before the"?" , in the URL...

Comment: "the file I expect to handle the request is index.php, placed just before the"?"" - In that case, it should appear in the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ string. However, if you "get a blank page" then that _could_ suggest the rewrite is "working", but it is a "fault" with your front-controller that is returning the "blank page" perhaps due to how it is analyzing the request. But this is all hypothetical. Without more detail this is impossible to answer. There's nothing technically wrong with the rule you've posted, but the points I've raised above are not going to help.

Comment: Hi again and thanks for your perseverance !
I have tweaked things a bit & put them online so that you can review "live", but still not working:
The .htaccess is as below:
`code` 
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php
    RewriteRule api/([^/]*)$ index.php?p=api.word.word_show&action=read_word_data&word=$1 [L]
    #RewriteRule api/([^/]*)$ index.php?p=api.word.word_show&action=read_word_data&word=$1

Comment: So `www.dictionnaire-commercial.com/api/.....` is intended to load to `www.dictionnaire-commercial.com/index.php?p=api.word.word_show&action=read_word_data&word=.....`?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php
RewriteRule api/([^/]*)$ index.php?p=api.word.word_show&action=read_word_data&word=$1 [L]
```

You've put your custom rewrite in the wrong place. As I mentioned in my first comment, "if you've placed this rule at the end of the file then that is a problem". This is because the request has already been written to `index.php` and the following rule (that matches `/api/<anything>`) never matches. In your original rule block, you used the `L` flag which would have meant the rule would not have been processed at all.

Your custom rewrite needs to go before the general rewrite to your front-controller.

However, the response from your server does not seem consistent:

1. `example.com/` - returns a valid response (your "homepage"?)
2. `example.com/does-not-exist` - returns the same as above (a valid 200 OK response)
3. `example.com/api` - literally returns a blank page (200 OK response)
4. `example.com/api/` - "File not found." and 404 response status
5. `example.com/api/does-not-exist` - As above - "File not found." and 404 response status.

So, there would seem to be "something else" going on here. From what you have posted, the response is presumably determined by `index.php`? However....

In looking at the HTTP responses, for `example.com/api` (no trailing slash) there is an additional header `content-location: api.php` and `vary: negotiate`. This would imply you have a file `api.php` and you have `MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation) enabled. MultiViews needs to be disabled for your rewrite to function as intended.

For example, try the following instead:

```
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^api/([^/]*)$ index.php?p=api.word.word_show&action=read_word_data&word=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I've also included a start-of-string anchor on the regex to avoid matching "too much".

Your rule also matches `/api/` only (with no second path segment) - is that a valid request?

This is still dependent on your front-controller (ie. `index.php`) correctly parsing the request. The last rule is a general front-controller pattern where you are perhaps reading the requested URL from the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` PHP superglobal. However, in your custom rewrite, you may need to override that behaviour?